# How can I change python version in anaconda console?

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, anaconda, conda

I want to make the default version of python to 3.5 (its currently 3.6 in the Anaconda console). I don't want to create a virtual environment, as I want to run everything line by line rather than executing everything at once.

Comment: Wait, why don't you want to create a `conda` environment? If you are in the environment, you can run your code however you want. Just make a python 3.5 environment. This is what conda is *for*.

Comment: I don't want a conda environment because I want to execute each line individually. Unless there is a way to do this in the conda environment without having to run the entire script?

Comment: ??? What? What do you mean? You mean use an interactive interpreter session? Or the Python debugger? In either case, both of those will use the Python interpreter of your current environment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Python and still learning. What I'm trying to say is that in the normal python 3.6 console, I can highlight a line and just execute that, without having to execute the rest of the script. But in the virtual environment, I have to execute everything at once.

Comment: What is a "normal python 3.6 console"? Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Spyder which automatically has python 3.6 in the console.

Comment: So, Spyder isnt' the "normal python 3.6 console"

Comment: So, if you are in your Python 3.5 anaconda environment, in the terminal, just use `spyder` and it *should* use the Spyder with the right interpreter.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217175/spyder-does-not-run-in-anaconda-virtual-environment-on-windows-10).