# unable to import gdal on mac, installed through anaconda

Tags: python, gdal

I'm getting the following error when I try to import gdal:

```
>>> from osgeo import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libgdal.20.dylib
  Referenced from: //anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling (it's installed with conda-forge), updating, and checking to make sure those files along the paths exists, but nothing seems to work! I also looked at a thread that suggested checking the .condarc file but can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

See the last comment on [this](https://github.com/conda-forge/fiona-feedstock/issues/13) page. This is a known issue. 
To save you the click:

> gdal depends on a huge number of c-libs
>   that need to be pinned down to specific versions to avoid software
>   breakage by mixing versions.
>
> The problem is that different channels pin to different versions. That
>   means you need to "stay" within a "trusted/consistent" pinning scheme.
>
> The Anaconda distribution brings a lot of pre-installed software and,
>   even by adding conda-forge as the preferred channel (placing it on top
>   of defaults), will be hard to get that consistent installation.
>
> **We recommend using miniconda and creating envs to "encapsulate" the
>   different cases and get a more stable installation. (Or, like I
>   mention above, if you don't need external channels you can use only
>   defaults.)**

Comment: ok so I've now done the following in terminal:

    conda create -n newenv python=3.6 gdal
    source activate newenv

if I'm coding in spyder does this now mean I have to open spyder from within that new environment? or is there another way?

Comment: @ESchreiber Correct, you need to either run it from there, or reinstall it in the environment. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170468/how-to-run-spyder-in-virtual-environment/30170469) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217175/spyder-does-not-run-in-anaconda-virtual-environment-on-windows-10).

Comment: unfortunately I'm still getting a similar error in my new environment (newenv). "ImportError: dlopen(/Users/echreiber/anaconda/envs/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libicui18n.58.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/eschreiber/anaconda/envs/newenv/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found"

Comment: @ESchreiber gdal requires very specific library versions. Try to force-install the exact versions gdal is looking for using `conda install -f library_name=library_version` for each library that you are getting an error for.

Comment: @ESchreiber Also, see [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/gdal-feedstock/issues/111).